# Efficient way to creating relationships with NoSQL database

Tags: nosql

I am currently trying to implement Tumblr-like user interactions like reblog, following, followers, commenting, blog posts of people who I currently following etc.
Also there is a requirement to display activity for each blog post.

I am stuck with creating proper schema for database. There are several way to achieve this kind of functionality (defining data structures embedded like blog posts and comments, creating an activity document for each action etc.) but I couldn't currently decide which way is the best in terms of performance and scalability.

For instance let's look at implementation of people who I follow. Here is sample User document.

```
User = { id: Integer, 
         username: String, 
         following: Array of Users,
         followers: Array of Users,
       }
```

This seems trivial. I can manage following field per user action (follow/unfollow) but what if an user who I currently follow is deleted. Is it effective to update all User records who  follows deleted user.

Another problem is creating a view of blog post from people who I follow.

```
 Post = { id: Integer, 
          author: User, 
          body: Text,
        }
```

So is it effective query latest posts like;

```
 db.posts.find( { author: { $in : me.followers} } )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems (to me) that you are trying to use a single data store (in this case a document-oriented NoSQL database) to fulfill (at least) two different requirements.  The first thing you seem to be trying to do is store data in a document-oriented store.  I am going to assume that you have legitimate reasons for doing this.

The second thing you seem to be trying to do is establish relationship(s) between the documents you are storing.  Your example shows a FOLLOWS relationship.  I would recommend treating this as a different requirement from storing data in a document-oriented NoSQL database and look at storing the relationships in a graph-oriented NoSQL database such as Neo4j.  This way, your entities can be stored in the document store and relationships in the graph store using just the document IDs.

My experience has been that it will be difficult (if not impossible) to get a single NoSQL database to meet all functional and non-functional needs of a medium to large sized application.  For example, the latest application I am working on uses MongoDB, Redis and Neo4j besides an RDBMS.  I spent a lot of time experimenting with technologies and settled on this combination.  I have committed myself to using Spring 3, along with the Spring Data project and so far my experience has been great.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I am actually using MongoDB which suits to Node.js very well. I don't want to use any other technology (because I have to learn it and deal with other problems as well) as long as if it can be implemented by using MongoDB effectively.

Comment: I can certainly see the temptation to continue attempting to use MongoDB for maintaining document relationships fearing that another technology will create more complexities.  However, this will be an unscalable solution in my opinion in general, except where the application in question is very small and will always be maintained by a single developer.  As the number of developers on the team will increase, each will have to understand the implications of updating and deleting documents on document relationships.  In the long run it will only cause more mistakes and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that works is called "Star Schema". If you search the web or wikipedia then you'll find lots of information.